# C# Dynamic Reference of Controls

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference, controls

Alright, so in summary:

I have 3 labels: lSectAvg1, lSectAvg2, lSectAvg3.

lMask is SUPPOSED to dynamically reference each of these through sequential iterations of this method, "CalcResults."

```
private void CalcResults(int[] numSet, int arrayCount, ref double max, ref double min)
    {
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        //lMask is assigned. First value is "lSectAvg1".
        Control lMask = this.Controls["lSectAvg" + arrayCount.ToString()];

        while (count < numSet.Count())
        {
            sum = sum + numSet[count];

            if (numSet[count] > max)
                max = numSet[count];
            if (min == 0 || numSet[count] < min)
                min = numSet[count];

            count++;
        }

        //Basically: "lSectAvg1.Text is set to the average."
        lMask.Text = (sum / count).ToString("n2");
    }
```

However, I end up with an error at the final line of code: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What gives? Should "this.Controls" be something different? Could it be a problem with the scope of my method / "Control" variable?

Basically: Is there something similar to an "EXEC" command in SQL that will execute strings as code?

Thanks a million!

EDIT: I should also add that the value of lMask after the error is thrown is "null".

Comment: Are you sure `arrayCount` is set to `1`, not `0`?

Comment: In hindsight, maybe it's not the cleanest method of pulling this off, but the method is called with:

CalcResults(arrayJagged[count], count + 1, ref max, ref min);

So, yes, I've confirmed it's 1.

Comment: And what is `this`? Is it the form? From what I remember, `this.Controls` only returns children, not all descendants. So you may need to change it to something like `somePanel.Controls` if the textboxes are within a panel

Comment: Your control is `null` because the form could not find the control with the specified name. Have you checked correctly that `"lSectAvg" + arrayCount.ToString()` is really what you think it is?

Comment: Rob-- It's a pretty basic program. All controls are contained on "Form1".

Philippe-- Yessir, I've replaced that section of code with just "lSectAvg1", and it returned the same error.

Comment: The count is total number of controls.  Your array is zero based therefor will be one less than count. Put a breakpoint on your method, look at your array and step through your method.

Answer (score 0):

DAMNIT. So, after working at this all day, I finally came across the answer.

For the record: if you're ever trying to reference something similar to what was demonstrated here, MAKE SURE YOU REFERENCE THE GROUPBOX IT'S CONTAINED IN AS WELL. `gbAvg.lSectAvg1` was the answer. I should have included that in the question, but I didn't even realize it was relevant.

Still, I appreciate the help, everyone.

Now that I've wasted entirely too much time on that, I can finally move on with my life...........